# Constructor was called when assignment operator not implemented

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I am practicing 'String' class implementation (C++) in Visual Studio 2015.
I have 3 constructors in my class and not any assignment operator.

```
String();
String(char _c);
String(const char* _pc);
```

In `main()`, i am deliberately using assignment operator to check behavior of the code.

To my surprise, it is not giving any error and uses the constructor `String(const char* _pc)` to assign value to the object.
Also, at the end of the scope, it is calling the destructor twice.

What is compiler doing behind the curtain in this case? and why?

Here is my code:

```
class String {
    private:
        int capacity;
        char* start;

    public:
        //Constructors
        String();
        String(const char* _pc);

        //Destructor
        ~String();
}

String::String() :start(nullptr), capacity(0) {}

String::String(const char* _pc) :capacity(1) {
    const char* buffer = _pc;

    while (*(buffer++))
        capacity++;

    int temp_capacity = capacity;
    if (temp_capacity)
        start = new char[temp_capacity];

    while (temp_capacity--) {
        start[temp_capacity] = *(--buffer);
    }
}

String::~String() {
    if (capacity == 1)
        delete start;
    if (capacity > 1)
        delete[] start;
}

int main() {
    String s;
    s="Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make your single argument constructors `explicit`.

Comment: `if (capacity == 1) delete start;` is a very bad idea. Even if you `new[]`ed a one-long array, you must delete it with `delete[]`. Or better, use an `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is compiler doing behind the curtain in this case?

Given `s="Hello World";`,

1. A temporary `String` is constructed (implicitly converted) from `"Hello World"` via `String::String(const char*)`.
2. `s` is assigned from the temporary via [implicitly-declared move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator) (`String::operator=(String&&)`).

BTW you might mark `String::String(const char*)` `explicit` to prohibit the implicit conversion which happened at step#1.